# Update for logged on user only - An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

First of all, please bear with me as I'm fairly new to MVC/Entity framework. I'm trying to do a partial update on an entity framework code first database for a specific authorized user using MVC5...

I've created an additional class called UserProfile to extend the asp.net Identity ApplicationUser class. Here's the code:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I've also extended the ApplicationUser class to include the UserProfile class as an additional property:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I've then extended the AccountController class (auto-generated using by asp.net Identity) to add an additional method called Welcome...

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Welcome([Bind(Include = "UserId,Username")] UserProfile userProfile)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        userProfile.ApplicationUser = user;

        db.UserProfile.Attach(userProfile);
        db.Entry(userProfile).Property(u => u.Username).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(userProfile);
}
```

However, when I attempt to submit the form and execute the Welcome method, I receive the following error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

I've tried the usual google searches to understand how/why this is happening but don't understand how I could have multiple instances of whatever IEntityChangeTracker is?

For further clarification, what I'm attempting to do here is ensure that only the current logged in user can update the UserProfile object (I can't find a nice pattern for this anywhere for some reason?).

I'm also aware that as the FK UserId is available on the UserProfile model, I could simply omit setting the userProfile.ApplicationUser and write a condition like this:

```
if (userProfile.UserId == user.Id)
```

However, from what I'm to understand about reading articles and tutorials on EF, this shouldn't be necessary in this instance? I'm also a little uneasy to be exposing the UserId property on the page, even as a hidden field.

So I suppose there's two questions here...

1. Why am I getting the multiple instances error and how do I resolve it?
2. What is the correct method/pattern to use to ensure that the user who is currently logged in is only able to update their own UserProfile?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is from the entity being tracked by two instances of your context. Namely, `UserManager` is instantiated with an instance of your application context, and then most likely you're defining another instance somewhere in your controller.

You fetch the user from the `UserManager` context, assign it the `UserProfile` instance, and then try to save the `UserProfile` instance into a separate context. This includes the user in the save, so now it's being tracked in two contexts. To fix it, you just need to ensure that you're only dealing with one context instance. Dependency injection is usually the best way to handle this.

However, you can side-step the issue entirely by simply not having `UserProfile`. The whole point of Identity is to give you extensible authentication classes that you can *extend*. `UserProfile` was necessary with SimpleMembership because the base user object, the ASP.NET Membership user, could *not* be extended. If you just add your profile properties onto your `ApplicationUser` class, as they should be, then you don't need to even work anything else.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I appreciate what you're saying with regards to not needing to extend the ApplicationUser class with UserProfile, however there will be a requirement for these data sets to be separate at some point in the future. Let's say for example that UserProfile wasn't an extension of the User object per-se (call it posts if you will) - wouldn't we have the same problem when attempting to update only a user's data?

Comment: Well, then that's where dependency injection becomes very important. Trust me. I put off implementing DI for a while when I was first getting started and it will hurt you in the long run. Start now doing it right.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of how DI might work in this instance? At the moment I'm just relying on Visual Studio's scaffolding to build controllers from my model.

Comment: A code sample is entirely dependent on what flavor of DI container you choose to go with. You'll need to do some research, first, and pick something that you'll be comfortable with. This list is a bit old, but I think most of them are still active: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx